# Can the limitations of std::align be checked at compile-time or runtime?

Tags: c++, c++11, alignment, language-lawyer, memory-alignment

I would like to align a region of memory which will be used for storage to a specific power-of-two alignment using [`std::align`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align)<sup>1</sup>.

This will apparently invoke UB if the alignment value isn't a *fundamental or extended alignment* value. Is there any way to check at compile-time (e.g., a `static_assert`) or at runtime whether the value I want to use is supported?

---

<sup>1</sup> To be clear, I'm also open to `std::alignas` or `std::aligned_storage` if they are more flexible or otherwise allow me to safely check what is supported.

Comment: Hmm.  Does "expression fails to be constexpr" trigger SFINAE?  If so, I think conditionally invoking UB in a `constexpr` function may be used to detect "is something UB" by having its invokation be in a SFINAE context for a trait, as UB makes something *not constexpr*.  But maybe not.

Comment: It isn't totally clear to me that it is UB either - I can't pay for a copy of the standard, but excerpts I've seen say that some values which are extended, but unsupported alignment values may be _ill-formed_ which would indicate an diagnostic (compile-failure) if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont That doesn't work for at least 3 reasons: (1) `std::align` is not constexpr, so any attempt to call it automatically makes the enclosing expression not a constant expression anyway; (2) compilers are not required to diagnose library UB in constant expressions; (3) it does not appear that the evaluation of a construct in a function body of a called function that makes the enclosing evaluation not a constant expression is considered an immediate context failure for SFINAE purposes (see related https://stackoverflow.com/a/75657087/481267)

Answer (score 0):

This is [LWG 2377](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2377) and it was fixed in C++17. It is noted in the issue description that

> it is not possible for the user to even determine whether a value is "a fundamental alignment value or an extended alignment value supported by the implementation in this context"

Thanks to the changes in C++17, you no longer need to worry about checking something that is impossible to check.